# Wcf service Host on another computer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I have found some topics about that but I can't find any solution to this.
When I host my WCF service on the same machine then everything is fine. But when I host it on another machine than client then problems appear.

When I invoke Open function from the client side then timeout exception occurs.

Server side config:

```
        <service name="Connectors.AppConnector">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageBinding" 
          contract="Contracts.IServiceContract">

        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="<ADDRESS>/MessengerService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

   <customBinding>
        <binding name="MessageBinding">
          <reliableSession />
          <compositeDuplex />
          <oneWay />
          <textMessageEncoding
                         messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10"
                         writeEncoding="utf-8" />
          <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                         bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                         proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                         realm=""
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Service-side code:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(manager.AppConnector);
host.Open();
```

Previously I had simple wsdualhttpbinding to support Callbacks but found solution like this to turn off security.

Client-side config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_IServiceContract">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="<ADDRESS>/MessengerService"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IServiceContract"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IServiceContract" name="CustomBinding_IServiceContract" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client-side code:

```
public class TestClass : IServiceContractCallback
{
    public void Start()
    {

        InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
        ServiceContractClient client = new ServiceContractClient(context);
        Console.WriteLine("Opening");
        client.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened");
    }

    public void MessageReceived(ServiceMessage message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MessageStatus(ServiceStatus status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It throws TimeoutException every time I try to connect with client. Firewall from Server Side is turned off, I can enter /MessengerService with browser. 
What is wrong?

Comment: What `<ADDRESS>` do you use?

Comment: http: // AddressIp:Port

Comment: are you sure that your servers firewall isn't simply blocking the incoming requests?

Comment: I am sure. I have no other firewalls. Everything works if I set basicHttpBinding. So it must be authentication problem...